# autohotkey flags keeps skipping my function

Tags: autohotkey

can you guys help me, i have added a flag, however it skips teleport() and keeps walksouth() any idea why? I'm kinda newbie here i hope you guys help me

```
    walk1 := 0
    loop {
        teleport()
    }


    teleport()
    {
    if (walk1 => 1)   ;this never worked  even i added flag walk1:=1 :(  please help 

                send, {f9}
                sleep, 500
                walk1 := 0
                return
}    else if (walk1 <= 0){ 
                 walksouth()
                 return

                }
        }



     walksouth() {   ;this keeps running and skipping teleport() 
            send, {f5}      
            sleep, 500
            walk1 := 1  ;added flag 1 to run the teleport, but still skipping
          return

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

**This is your corrected and refactored code:**

```
walk := false
loop {
  teleport()
}


teleport()
{
  global walk

  if (walk) {
    send {f9}
    walk := false
  } else { 
    send {f5}
    walk := true
  }
  sleep 500
}
```

---

**Bugs in your code:**

- Variables in functions have local scope unless they are declare using `global`. So the `walk1` variables in your functions and the global `walk1` are all different variables
- You are missing an open brace `{` after if `(walk1 => 1)`